# JQGrid Edit form setting focus on an element

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Hi I have a jqGrid setup and I am trying to set the focus on one of my input boxes after the Edit Form loads. My code is as follows:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    $(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid, { left: '250', afterShowForm: function (formid) {   
          console.log('Bong');  
           $('elementID').focus(); } 
});
```

The "Bong" is displayed, the event triggers, but the focus command doesn't seem to work, and my google-fu doesn't seem to be coming up with an answer for why this wouldn't be working.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
  My code with a $('#elementID').focus(); still did not work so I implemented Oleg's delay suggestion below and it started to work the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you have just typing error in your code: you should use

```js
$('#elementID').focus();
```

instead of

```js
$('elementID').focus();
```

In some situations it's needed to place the code in `setTimeout(function() {/*here*/}, 50);` block, but I think it's unneeded in your case.

Comment: Sorry, but when I sanitized my code for posting this I removed the hash.  I did have a properly formatted jQuery Selector which didn't work.  I did try your setTimeout delay function and that seemed to get me the functionality I was looking for.  Oleg strikes again! We need an Oleg Batman like symbol to throw up in the air!